# Sales order email is not working in magento2

Tags: magento2, order-email

Sales order email is not working in magento2. Remaining mails working fine only customer not able to receive email after placing order.

Comment: can you check error log? Is there any third party extension the affect this.

Comment: some time mail sent to spam. check it is in spam mail.